# Nagios Check - Scripting

Tags: mac-osx, bash

If I hard code the process I want to find and run script a

Script A

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS=/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Resources/quicklookd.app/Co

number=$(ps aux | grep $PROCESS | wc -l)

if [ $number -le 1 ]
        then
        echo "Nope - This seems NOT to be Running"
        exit 2
else
        if [ $number -ge 2 ]
        then
        echo "This seems to be Running"
        exit 0
        fi
fi
```

The script gives me the answer I expect.

If I run Script B like this ./scriptb.sh `/System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Resources/quicklookd.app/Co`

It always comes back as "This seems to be Running" even if I put sakdjnsakjsakfndsdkjnf as they arguement?

```
#!/bin/bash

number=$(ps aux | grep $1 | wc -l)

if [ $number -le 1 ]
        then
        echo "Nope - This seems NOT to be Running"
        exit 2
else
        if [ $number -ge 2 ]
        then
        echo "This seems to be Running"
        exit 0
        fi
fi
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Exclude `grep ` from the results: `number=$(ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v grep | wc -l)`

Comment: Even if I do that dave@gx tmp]$ ps aux | grep kjdsjkdsjk | grep -v grep | wc -l
0
dave@gx tmp]$ ./test.sh kjdsjkdsjk
This seems to be Running ---- Same result if I change the le to eq "0" and the ge "1"

Answer (score 2):

grep locates itself in the processlist.

Use pgrep to search for a process. Something like:

```
T=$(pgrep -f "$PROCESS")

if test -z "$T" ; then
 ...
else
 ...
fi
```

should do the trick.